# Ajax запрос в asp.net mvc 4 вместо обновления указанного элемента <div> открывает новую страницу с результатом запроса

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

пытался делать все по гайдам вот отсюда https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/10.3.php ,тем не менее этот код

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BookSearch", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results"}))
{
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Поиск" />
}
<div id="results"></div>
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

вместо обновления элемента results Открывает страницу метода BookSearch c его частичным представленем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не загрузился "~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" (и, возможно, "~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"), навешивающий обработчики `submit` на формы с `data-ajax="true"`.

Oткройте инструменты разработчика браузера (F12) и, просмотрев список скриптов, найдите/не найдите там этот файл.

Найдите во "View Source" страницы браузера тэг `script` с этим файлом, попробуйте загрузить только этот файл в отдельной вкладке, набрав `src`-атрибут скрипта, конечно, с протоколом и доменом впереди.

Убедитесь, что директорий `scripts` корня сайта содержит оба js файла.

Comment: А как их подгрузить? В списке скриптов есть, в лэйаут тоже

Answer (score 1):

Все, я разобрался. Если у кого то возникнет та же проблема-установите nuget, обновите unobotrosive и jquerry, а потом при подключении через
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
3.1.1. замените на те цифры, которые у вас указаны в папке scripts
ps огромное спасибо товарищу Игорю, думал уже ничего не спасет

Comment: рад, что Вам удалось найти, в чем было дело. Здесь принято отмечать ответ, который оказался Вам полезен, щёлкнув по галочке слева от ответа. Успехов!